# Random pie chart applet

Tags: java, html, charts, applet, jcreator

Hi guys I have to write a applet for creating a pie chart. However I have to do it with random class. I could write it if I it was without random but right now i have no idea how can i write it. I mean I can define startang with x, y, z... but this time sum of them would not be 360 so it wont work. Basically it should be like this

http://i61.tinypic.com/20j0ape.png

but creating that number randomly and make startang with respect to these numbers

Answer (score 1):

This is what you *could* do:

1. Have a method which takes an array of numbers. *
2. Have the method add up all the numbers -> This is your 100%
3. Express each percentage as `(current number / total) * 360` this would be the size of the angle, **in degrees** that your slice needs to be for a particular value. (this will be `angle(n)`)
4. The slice will start at `angle(n-1)` and will move `angle(n)`. (The next will start at `angle(n-2) + angle(n-1)`.

* If you want to go after labeled graphs, you could create an object, such as a `PieChartItem` which takes in a `double` (value) and a `string` (label).

Comment: [link]https://pastebin.com/EeH89nUd I have written as this but there is still a problem with angles? whats wrong?

Comment: @Emre: What do you mean by problem? If the angles are off set, this could be due to the way the `fillArc` works.